# Edit Laravel framework files on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have a Laravel app on Heroku that I would like to edit a framework file on (Request.php to be specific). But when I push the changes, it seems to get overwritten by the server.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel framework files are inside vendor folder which are ignored by git. i.e in you .gitignroe file. So any changes you make won't be push to heroku until you removed them from .gitignore. Also, alternating the vendor folder is not a good practice. If you want to overwrite them then don't directly modify them. You can use marcos for this. [Look here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses) to know about marcos more, the docs are clear and on point

```
Response::macro('foo', function($value){
    //You custom task
    return Response::make($value);
});
```

Comment: I force commited the file through the command line. ;)
But I'll look into Macros, thank you.